# ¿Cómo integrar babel luego de haber generado un proyecto con express -generator?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Estoy aprendiendo a integrar babel en mi proyecto con node. He visto varios tutoriales pero todos ponen ejemplos de servidores creados en un fichero de prueba, sin embargo yo estoy usando express -generator el cual me genera ya una serie de ficheros y puedo correr directamente mi proyecto con el comando npm start. el asunto está en el scripts del package.json no se cómo configurarlo de modo que me compile bien.

Los pasos que he seguido hasta el momento son los siguientes:

```
npm install express -generator -g
express --view=pug paladar
npm install
npm install babel-cli --save
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

también he creado el fichero con la extención .babelrc en el directorio raiz
con la siguiente configuración:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Alguien me pudiera dar una mano?

Este es mi package.json:

```
{
  "name": "paladar",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "devstart": "babel ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {

  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías agregar lo que tienes en la sección de scripts de tu `package.json`?

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta agregando el package.json @MauricioContreras: gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola @WilberLunaJiménez. Yo utilice este tutorial para iniciar un proyecto con babel. Talvez te sirva como referencia para hacer los cambios correspondientes. https://medium.com/@purposenigeria/build-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-express-js-d7e59c7a3dfb

Answer (score 0):

Hola te dejo un enlace que explica como hacerlo.

https://medium.com/@j_cunanan05/how-to-enable-es6-and-beyond-syntax-with-node-and-express-c7110406b480 [Como transpilar express con babel][1]